# How to read special characters in the text file using pandas.to_excel()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have huge text file which i want to export to the excel by first doing some operations by making it a dataframe using Python.

Now, the file contains some special characters in one of the Header which is why i am not able to export that header line data from the DataFrame to the excel.

Its is something like this

{"ÿþ""DOEClientID""",DOEClient,ChgClientID,ChgClient,ChgSystemID,ChgSystem}

I am able to export the data when i use {header = False} property but it shows some error when i make this header property TRUE

Please Help me Out with , I have searched a lot but not able to find any solution.
I need those headers in the file.

COde:
    `def files(file_name, outfile_name):
    data_initial = open(path + file_name, "rU")
    data1 = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in data_initial), delimiter=",")

```
reader = csv.reader(open(path + file_name, 'rU'))
writer = csv.writer(open(path + outfile_name ,'wb'),dialect = 'excel')
for row in data1:
    writer.writerow(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(path + outfile_name,sep=',', engine='python'))

final_frame = df.dropna(how='all')

file_list = list(uniq(list(final_frame['DOEClient'])))

return file_list, final_frame`
```

Comment: That is [utf-16 little endian BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) you should be able to set the encoding to 'utf-16' when loading and writing, otherwise just strip it out

Comment: Can you post code showing how you load the data, a couple sample data lines and your code to write this out, it should be pretty simple, either specify the encoding when you import the data, or after importing remove that column or specify the encoding when you write it out

Comment: Hi EdChum,  I Have tried specifying the encoding as utf-16 or utf-32 bu then it is giving me this error. { CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'. }

Comment: So does it work if you also pass param `engine='python'`? Also edit your code into the question not in the comments

Comment: After specifying the engine it giving this error `UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM`

Comment: You've not posted your input data, also post the output from `df.info()` after loading

Comment: I mentioned the input data in the question section. its the first line of the data which is I am using.

Comment: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 109-110: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: You're telling me that your input data is exactly like this:`{"ÿþ""DOEClientID""",DOEClient,ChgClientID,ChgClient,ChgSystemID,ChgSystem}` with braces and only quotes around the first 2 elements?

Comment: Actually My original Data is like this : `"DOEClientID","DOEClient","ChgClientID","ChgClient","ChgSystemID"`             After using replace and putting data into the text file from original csv...it looks like above mentioned one which is going in the dataframe.

Comment: I'm going to have to ask again as you still have not provided this, please post your raw input data, not your cleaned data, not something **like** your data, the actual data or a link where I can download it, this is turning into a monumental waste of my time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70515/discussion-between-user2558422-and-edchum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your input file is that it has a [utf-16 little endian BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) this is why you see the funny characters: `ÿþ` which is `0xFFFE` but is being displayed using ISO-8859-1.

So you just need to pass the param `encoding=utf-16'` in order to be able to read the file fine:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, encoding='utf-16')
```